# How do I specify Origin Whitelist Options in Sinatra using Rack/Protection

Tags: sinatra, rack, cors

I have a web app, lets say http://web.example.com making a POST request to http://api.example.com.  The api server is running the latest version of Sinatra with rack protection enabled.  I am getting this error 'attack prevented by Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin'.

I can do something like this:

```
set :protection, :except => [:http_origin]
```

but I feel like I am just ignoring the actual problem.

I have tried to do this:

```
use Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin, :origin_whitelist => ['http://web.example.com']
```

but I still get the warning.

The request does not get rejected, but Sinatra clears my session [see this post](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/508) and I need the session_id.

Any help or examples on how to specify the option_whitelist for the HttpOrigin class would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `use Rack::Protection, :origin_whitelist => ['http://web.example.com']` ? Looking at [the source](https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection/blob/master/lib/rack/protection/http_origin.rb), I think you can dispose of the array too (unless you're adding several paths) as a single string is wrapped in an array anyway.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  I got my original example from the libraries spec tests [here](https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection/blob/master/spec/http_origin_spec.rb)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pass your options as a hash to `set :protection`:

```
set :protection, :origin_whitelist => ['http://web.example.com']
```

Sinatra will then pass them through to `Rack::Protection` when setting it up.

I suspect the reason it is failing when you have `use Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin, :origin_whitelist => ['http://web.example.com']` is that you still have protection enabled, so that you end up with *two* instances of `HttpOrigin`. You could try

```
set :protection, :except => [:http_origin]
use Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin, :origin_whitelist => ['http://web.example.com']
```

(i.e. have both the lines you’ve tried *together*), but I think the first solution is cleaner.