# CORS trouble between Sinatra and AngularJS

Tags: rest, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, sinatra

I'm in troubles with a very basic web app. Here are my files:

## public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" data-ng-app>
  <body>

    <div data-ng-controller="PlayersCtrl">
      <div data-ng-repeat="player in players">
        {{player.id}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/players.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## public/players.js

```
function PlayersCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.players = [];

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:9292/hi'
  }).success(function(data) {
    $scope.players = data;
  });
}
```

## client.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Authorization,Accepts,Content-Type,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With'
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'

  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'index.html')
end
```

## api.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

get '/hi' do
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Authorization,Accepts,Content-Type,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With'
  headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'

  [id: 1, name: "Bob"].to_json
end
```

To me, this seems good. Then, I start the servers:

## Starting api.rb

```
$ ruby api.rb -p 9292
[2013-03-07 23:57:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-03-07 23:57:43] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
== Sinatra/1.3.5 has taken the stage on 9292 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-03-07 23:57:43] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=62634 port=9292
```

## Starting client.rb

```
$ ruby client.rb
[2013-03-07 23:57:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-03-07 23:57:40] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
== Sinatra/1.3.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2013-03-07 23:57:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=62610 port=4567
```

But when I go with a browser on localhost (port 4567), I have the following logs:

## api.rb logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2013 23:57:46] "OPTIONS /hi HTTP/1.1" 404 442 0.0015
localhost - - [07/Mar/2013:23:57:46 CET] "OPTIONS /hi HTTP/1.1" 404 442
http://localhost:4567/ -> /hi
```

## client.rb logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2013 23:57:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0093
localhost - - [07/Mar/2013:23:57:46 CET] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0
- -> /
```

I did a lot a search about *Cross-origin resource sharing* and I tested many different ways. I currently have no idea how to process. Thank you for any help.

**Edit:**

My problem is that, the api.rb server return an `error 404` after the AngularJS call. Moreover, there is two `OPTIONS /hi` requests, which is weird. I think it's a CORS symptom, but I added some header in order to accept cross-origin queries.

Instead of this, the server should return a `200` with the JSON. I really don't see how to fix it.

Comment: Doug, I see an lot of data but little information, specifically, what's the problem?!! It's helpful to really spell it out near the title.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes my question wasn't very clear. I just updated it...

Comment: Have you looked at the [Rack CORS middleware](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)? It would handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 6):

I had to add the following to my sinatra app to get it to work with CORS and angular:

```
options "*" do
  response.headers["Allow"] = "HEAD,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"

  # Needed for AngularJS
  response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Accept"

  halt HTTP_STATUS_OK
end
```

I also used [sinatra-cross_origin](https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin), but you might not need that seeing as you set the headers manually.

Comment: I also had to add this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14086296/111884 to remove the `attack prevented by Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin` error

Comment: wouldn't this just disable the whole thing?